# Ordering within group and selecting non-null values

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table with data merged from several sources, and I would like to:

- Group by a column `x`
- Within each group, order by column `z`, preferring non-`NULL` values
- For other columns within each group, take the first non-`NULL` value according to the order defined

Here's example input, call it table `t`:

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a0 | NULL |
| a | NULL | 1 |
| a | a2 | 2 |
| b | b1 | 1 |
| b | b2 | 2 |

And desired output:

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a2 | 1 |
| b | b1 | 1 |

### `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`

My first thought was to use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`:

```sql
select x, min(y), min(z)
from t
group by x
order by y
```

But I get

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

B/c, IIUC, the order of operations is `GROUP BY`, then `SELECT` the aggregates, then `ORDER BY`, so `ORDER BY` can only operate on what's in `SELECT`. That's not what I want.

### FIRST_VALUE

I did manage to get the desired output with [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions057.htm):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    x,
    FIRST_VALUE(y IGNORE NULLS)
    OVER(PARTITION BY x
        ORDER BY
            z
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) y,
    FIRST_VALUE(z IGNORE NULLS)
    OVER(PARTITION BY x
        ORDER BY
            z
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) z
FROM
    t;
```

but this just seems extremely verbose & repetitive. Is there a better solution where the window can be specified *once* rather than for each column?

Comment: The `rows between...` lines don't seem necessary. If your concern with the working `FIRST_VALUE` solution is that it's too verbose, have you considered removing that?

Comment: They are necessary. W/out them, I get an extra `| a | NULL | 1 |`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not realize it is using `distinct` to get rid of duplicates. I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`match_recognize`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/dwhsg/sql-pattern-matching-data-warehouses.html#GUID-136DAC89-DA17-45C6-9E37-C9892723AC79) to capture rows with non-null values and reference them in a `measures` clause:

> ```
> select x, y, z
> from test_tab
> match_recognize (
>   partition by x
>   order by z asc nulls last
>   measures
>     /*The first value of Z (nulls last)*/
>     first(any_.z) as z,
>     /*The first non-null value of Y:
>         captured either by any_ pattern
>         or by other that skips all nulls first
>     */
>     coalesce(first(any_.y), first(other.y)) as y
>   /*Any row
>     followed by zero or more Y with null
>     followed by any number of any non-null Y rows for the same X
>   */
>   pattern (any_ y_null* other*)
>   define
>     y_null as y is null
> )
> ```

Or from [Oracle 21c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Changes-in-This-Release-for-Oracle-Database-SQL-Language-Reference.html#GUID-3C11D3A9-8B14-4DCC-B212-B7FE57EE81E8) you may reuse [window specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) by declaring it at the bottom of `select` statement and use your original approach:

> ```
> select distinct
>   x,
>   first_value(y ignore nulls) over fv as y,
>   first_value(z ignore nulls) over fv as z
> from test_tab
> window fv as (
>   partition by x
>   order by z asc nulls last
>   rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
> )
> ```

Given this sample data:

> ```
> create table test_tab(X, Y, Z) as
>   select 'a', 'a0', NULL from dual union all
>   select 'a', NULL, 1 from dual union all
>   select 'a', 'a2', 2 from dual union all
>   select 'b', 'b1', 1 from dual union all
>   select 'b', 'b2', 2 from dual
> ```

both the queries return this result:

> | X | Y | Z |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | a | a2 | 1 |
> | b | b1 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1ebc59c8b395249f905878e866947828)*

Comment: Oh man, wish we were on Oracle 21c! That would make things much easier.